# C# settings not saved while running .exe separately

Tags: c#, settings

My problem is that when i run my .exe file separately the settings are not saved, but when i start my application in Visual Studio it works fine. The settings scope is set to user.
I am using the following code to save a `StringCollection` to settings:

```
internal void SaveFileHistory(string filepath) //saves previously opened file's paths to settings
{
    List<string> paths = OpenFileHistory().Cast<string>().ToList();
    if (!paths.Contains(filepath))
    {
        if (paths.Count() == 10)
        {
            paths.RemoveAt(0);
            paths.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
            paths.Add(filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            paths.Add(filepath);
        }
        StringCollection collection = new StringCollection();
        collection.AddRange(paths.ToArray());
        Properties.Settings.Default.OpenedFileHistory = collection;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping!